# Dependency Injection to Play Framework 2.5 modules

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection

I have a module class with the following signature:

```
class SilhouetteModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
```

I would like to inject configuration:

```
class SilhouetteModule @Inject() (configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
```

But it fails with the following error.

```
No valid constructors
Module [modules.SilhouetteModule] cannot be instantiated.
```

The Play documentation mentions that

> In most cases, if you need to access Configuration when you create a component, you should inject the Configuration object into the component itself or...

, but I can't figure out how to do it successfully. So the question is, how do I inject a dependency into a module class in Play 2.5?

Comment: The example above the part you're quoting doesn't make use of the `@Inject` annotation, it merely says and shows that you can add constructor arguments. Have you tried that?

Comment: What is `ScalaModule` or `AbstractModule`? Modules aren't really supposed to have any constructor parameters. They are supposed to provide bindings for classes that may need to inject things (or not). What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solutions to solve your problem.

**First one** (and the more straight forward one):
Do not extend the `com.google.inject.AbstractModule`. Instead use the `play.api.inject.Module`. Extending that forces you to override `def bindings(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration): Seq[Binding[_]]`. Within that method you could do all your bindings and you get the configuration inserted as a method-parameter.

**Second one** (and the more flexible one):
Depending on your needs of the components you want to inject, you could define a provider for the component you want to bind. In that provider you could inject whatever you want. E.g.

```
import com.google.inject.Provider

class MyComponentProvider @Inject()(configuration:Configuration) extends Provider[MyComponent] {
    override def get(): MyComponent = {
        //do what ever you like to do with the configuration
        // return an instance of MyComponent
    }
}
```

Then you could bind your component within your module:

```
class SilhouetteModule extends AbstractModule {
    override def configure(): Unit = {
        bind(classOf[MyComponent]).toProvider(classOf[MyComponentProvider])
    }
}
```

The advantage of the second version, is that you are able to inject what ever you like. In the first version you get "just" the configuration.

Comment: Thank you! Just for the record, here's how I solved it in the end: https://github.com/grantzvolsky/websecute-frontend/commit/b14e5f415640a2a62be8c691c30a738ccb9d3abe

Comment: The second is more appropriate because it need not be `Configuration` but can be other classes such as `ExecutionContext` or database sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor signature from:

```
class SilhouetteModule @Inject() (configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule
```

to:

```
class SilhouetteModule(env: Environment, configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule
```

see here for more info:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/8474