# Play WS client within a module

Tags: playframework, guice, ws-client

I am trying to use the WS client with play 2.7.4 inside a module and I am running into issues. I would prefer to not create the client myself as described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWS#Directly-creating-WSClient) but rather dependency inject it with guice. This doesn't seem to work, my instance is null. If I use the WS client outside the module, everything works.

According to what I read [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/8474#issuecomment-398235500) only Config and Environment are available at that point from within the module, nothing else is bound yet.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

---

### [edit 1]

What i understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45415051/811257) is to create a provider class like this where I inject it normally

```
public class WSClientProvider implements Provider<WSClient> {

WSClient wsClient;

@Inject
public WSClientProvider(WSClient wsClient) {
    this.wsClient = wsClient;
}

@Override
public WSClient get() {
    return wsClient;
}
```

}

and then inside the module to just bind it like this

```
bind(WSClient.class).toProvider(WSClientProvider.class);
```

But this is not working in my case. What am I missing here?

---

### [edit 2]

This is my module at the moment

```
public class SecurityModule extends AbstractModule {

private final Environment environment;
private final Config configuration;

public SecurityModule(final Environment environment, final Config configuration) {
    this.environment = environment;
    this.configuration = configuration;
}

@Override
protected void configure() {
    ...some bindings...
}

@Provides
private ObjectA provideMyObjectA() {
    return new ObjectA(); <-- we want to inject the WSClient inside this object

}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete source code for the module?

Comment: @TimMoore Added, does it make it any clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to take it a little further

```
public class ObjectAProvider implement Provider<ObjectA> {
     @Inject
     WSClient wsClient;

     public ObjectA get() {
          return new ObjectA(wsClient);
     }
}
```

Or you'd have to manually inject within the provider method:

```
ObjectA objectA = injector.getInstance(ObjectA.class);
return objectA;
```

Once you have the injector created.

Comment: This fixed it! What I needed was indeed to convert the @Provides for ObjectA into a separate provider class and inject the WSClient in there